# Winforms C# Monopoly - Move player around board

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a monopoly game in C# using winforms, and I need to deal with the player icons being moved around the board.

I was thinking about doing it like so;

```
    private void movePlayerToNewSquare(int playerPos)
    {
        int playerPosition = playerPos;

        switch (playerPosition)
        {
            case 0:
                playerIcon1.Location = pictureBox1.Location;
                break;
            case 1:
                playerIcon1.Location = pictureBox2.Location;
                break;
```

playerPos is from an earlier function and is an int from 0 to 39, with their location on the board being that number in a list of all the squares on the board i.e 0 = "Go", 1 = "Old Kent Road" etc. And I was thinking of having a different case for each square on the board. But this seems like a long winded way of doing things.

I was wondering if there is a way in C# where I can use the playerPosition integer as the number following pictureBox, maybe something like;

```
pictureBox(playerPosition).Location
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try using a dictionary of <position number, <pos x, pos y>>.

Comment: If you have all the squares in a list, then just use the list index: `playerIcon1.Location = squares[playerPos].Location;`

Comment: And if you have the number that they rolled, like `int diceValue`, then you can just do: `playerIcon1.Location = squares[(currentPosition + diceValue) % 40].Location;`

Answer (score 1):

One way you can try is to create a GameSquare class and inherit from PictureBox.  Then you create an Id property in GameSquare, generate a List of Gamesquares which are Ids 1 - 40.

Add a property to your player class to keep track of what square they are and match the location with the GameSqaure location.  Something like this:

```
public class Player : PictureBox
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int currentGameSquare { get; set; }
    //etc, etc
}
public class GameSquare : PictureBox
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    //etc..etc.     
}

 public class Game
{
   private List<GameSquare> gameBoard;
   private Player p;

    //you're going to populate square values and title somewhere else in your code.
    Dictionary<string, int> squareValues = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public Game()
    {
        gameBoard = new List<GameSquare>();
        p = new Player();

        GenerateGameBoard(40);
    }

   public void GenerateGameBoard(int numSquares)
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < gameBoard.Count(); i++)
        {
            GameSquare s = new GameSquare()
            {
                Id = i,
                Name = gameBoard.ElementAt(i).Key
                Value = gameBoard.ElementAt(i).Value
                Location = new Point(someX, someY)  //however your assigning the board layout
                //Assign the rest of the properties however you're doing it
            };
            gameBoard.Add(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, when the player rolls, you could do something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();

int[] dice = new int[2];
dice[0] = r.Next(1,6);
dice[1] = r.Next(1,6);
movePlayertoNewSquare(dice);

private void movePlayerToNewSquare(int[] diceroll)
{
    p.currentGameSquare += diceroll.Sum();
    //You would need logic to determine if the player passed go and account for that

    p.Location = gameBoard.Where(x => x.id == p.currentGameSquare).Single().Location);

}
```

Hopefully you get the idea

Comment: i like the idea of two calls to r.Next but r.Next(1,6) as there are two dice..and if both are the same then its another roll like when you get a double, and ifs its 3 doubles in a row its go to jail. and techincally as you have two dice the shortest/smallest move is 2? so then it would be Next(2,12)

Comment: Good point.  I didn't consider doubles and whatnot.  I edited the code a bit to account for it

Comment: Thanks for the response, the only problem is this is for a uni assignment, and we haven't covered classes yet, and are expected to do this without them.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find an easy way to do this, although this is only set up for one player so I'll need to adjust it in the future.

```
    private void movePlayerToNewSquare(int playerPos)
    {
        int playerPosition = playerPos;

        Control[] pB = this.Controls.Find("pictureBox" + (playerPosition + 1).ToString(), true);

        playerIcon1.Location = pB[0].Location;
        player1Offset();
    }
```